# Create nested Java TreeMap in Scala

Tags: scala, dictionary

I want to create a nested  tree map in Scala from 2 lists
Eg

```
private val a = List(0, 100000, 500000, 1000000)
private val b = List (0, 5, 25, 50)
```

I want the nested tree map to contain keys as the values from list a. The value for these keys would be another tree map that contains keys as the values from list b with values as a default value. To clarify, here's the format in which i want the tree map-default value being 0.:

```
{
0:{
0:0,
5:0,
25:0,
50:0
},
100000:{
0:0,
5:0,
25:0,
50:0
},
..}
```

Is there an efficient way to do this in Scala?

Edit: I want to use the same logic but use a Java Tree Map in Scala instead. Could someone please guide me?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach to get it into the requested shape. There may be more efficient ways to do this for a large data set.

```
a.flatMap(aa => TreeMap(aa -> b.flatMap(bb => TreeMap(bb -> 0)).toMap))

val res50: List[(Int, Map[Int, Int])] = 

  List(
   (0,      Map(0 -> 0, 5 -> 0, 25 -> 0, 50 -> 0)), 

   (100000, Map(0 -> 0, 5 -> 0, 25 -> 0, 50 -> 0)),

   (500000, Map(0 -> 0, 5 -> 0, 25 -> 0, 50 -> 0)),

   (1000000,Map(0 -> 0, 5 -> 0, 25 -> 0, 50 -> 0))
  )
```

Comment: I want the outer structure to be TreeMap as well.Not a List. Is that possible?

Comment: Ya, you can call `toMap`.

Comment: Sorry but wont this create regular Map instead of TreeMap?

Comment: You're correct. My mistake. `TreeMap.from(...)` will do it.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is:

```scala
a.iterator.map { aa =>
  aa -> b.iterator.map(bb => bb -> 0).to(TreeMap.canBuildFrom)
}.to(TreeMap.canBuildFrom)
```

---

*You can see the code running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/5y9LM21KQpaHBVO5w6mj4g/2)*

Comment: Gave me the following error:                                                                                         
   error: type mismatch;
[scalac-2.12]  found   : scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap.type
[scalac-2.12]  required: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Nothing,(Int, Int),?]
[scalac-2.12]         aa -> b.iterator.map(bb => bb -> 0).to(TreeMap)

Comment: @Pottermore1010 ah you should have clarified you were using **Scala** `2.12` can't you upgrade to `2.13`?

Comment: Sorry about that. No can't upgrade unfortunately

Comment: @Pottermore1010 See edited answer.

Comment: Thank you! However this created object of type  Iterable[(Int, Iterable[(Int, Int)])] and not TreeMap[Int, TreeMap[Int, Int]]

Answer (score 1):

And using `foldLeft`

```
a.foldLeft(TreeMap.empty[Int, TreeMap[Int, Int]]) { (acc, elem) =>
  acc + (elem -> b.map(bKey => bKey -> 0)
    .to(TreeMap.canBuildFrom)) 
    //.to(TreeMap)) //if you use 2.13
}
```